# WinAPI function which replaces file but preserves file information

Tags: winapi, file, datemodified

I remember there was a WinAPI function which copied the "date modified" property of the previous file which was replaced with it or something like that? Perhaps anyone can tell me about it?

The problem occured when you used that function very frequently.

Answer (score 1):

This is [ReplaceFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365512%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (Windows 2000 and up):

> The ReplaceFile function combines
>   several steps within a single
>   function. An application can call
>   ReplaceFile instead of calling
>   separate functions to save the data to
>   a new file, rename the original file
>   using a temporary name, rename the new
>   file to have the same name as the
>   original file, and delete the original
>   file. Another advantage is that
>   ReplaceFile not only copies the new
>   file data, but also preserves the
>   following attributes of the original
>   file:
>
> - Creation time
> - Short file name
> - Object identifier
> - DACLs
> - Encryption
> - Compression
> - Named streams not already
>     in the replacement file

Answer (score 0):

Not too clear exactly what you want, but it seems your after [`SetFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724933%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to edit and `GetFileTime` to copy, combining the two you can do exactly as 'described/wanted'